# Managed DLL injection?

Tags: c#, dll, code-injection, managed

Basically I want to take a c# dll, encrypt it and save this as a file. Then another application opens this file decrypt it back into a byte array and without saving this to a file call a method in this decrypted buffer in memory. So far I have only been able to do this on unmanaged dll but I was wondering if there was anyone here who could help me get an idea of what I should do since I found almost no info after spending hours on google.

Comment: Use "load assembly from byte array" as search term instead of "cute kittens"

Comment: Doesn't load assembly only work on unmanaged dlls ?

Comment: @ShaamilAhmed, why should "load assembly" be concerned with non-assembly (i.e., unmanaged) dlls?

Answer (score 1):

Check out `Assembly.Load(byte[])` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7(v=vs.110).aspx